# How do I remove the last part of every line in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I know this can be done in notepad++, but I'm not finding the right replace syntax.

I want to remove the last part of this sentence, starting from `?`:

```
http://sportnaslava.info/wiki/index.php?title=User:CisBlakeman861
```

so that it becomes:

```
http://sportnaslava.info/wiki/index.php
```

Answer (score 20):

The regexp is `\?.*$`

```
\? mean question mark itself
.* mean everything else
$ means the end of line.
```

So we search something starting with question mark and lasts to the end of line.
Don't forget to set "search mode" to "regular expression"

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot man that helped and what about lines with out ? example http://lunar.earth.northwestern.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Limitless_It_the_film_high_quality  replace to http://lunar.earth.northwestern.edu/mediawiki/index.php/

Answer (score 5):

```
http://lunar.earth.northwestern.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Limitless_It_the_film_high_quality
http://sportnaslava.info/wiki/index.php?title=User:CisBlakeman861
```

Using those examples, it would be better to use something like:

```
index\.php.*$
```

Then replace with:

```
index.php
```

That should find everything after (and including) index.php, and replace it with just index.php.

```
http://lunar.earth.northwestern.edu/mediawiki/index.php
http://sportnaslava.info/wiki/index.php
```

Comment: thank you so much, putnik, alex and josh you guys solved it